# How to show tt_news related articles in bottom

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tt-news

I use tt_news 8.7 and Typo3 8.7, in news single view i like to show related news articles (same category) as Image/Teaser boxes at the bottom of the page, is this possible with tt_news ? can this be done by typoscript or changing the templates ?

Best regards,
Masmoudi M.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tt_news has an option to show related news by category in the single view. You can activate it by setting `plugin.tt_news.showRelatedNewsByCategory = 1` in TypoScript. In your single template you have to have the marker `###NEWS_RELATED_BY_CATEGORY###`. It will replace this with a list view of the related items.

More on this can be found here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/tt_news/Manual/Index.html#related-news-by-category

Comment: Very sad that this can't show the image and the subheader of the news item, is there any way to get it ? or Can i rework this with typoscript ?

Comment: It's the same as the normal list view, so you can get anything you can get in there, including the image and subheader. If you want a different template for the related items, see the link I posted.